# Best approach, for joining controls in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to know, what is the best approach, for joining controls in winforms. For example: When I want has a button, with a label, that counts clicks.

First one is that I prepare controls in my winform designer, and then send them to the constructor of my ClicksCount1 class. This is good, when I want easily position my controls to each other.

Second one is coupling controls in a panel. It’s better, because I will have that, in my toolbox.

Third one is similar solution to second, but without a panel.

1.

```
    public class ClicksCount1
{
    Button _oButton;
    Label _oLabel;

    int _clickCount = 0;
    public int ClickCount {
        get {
            return _clickCount;
        }
        set {
            _clickCount = value;
            _oLabel.Text = _clickCount.ToString();
        }
    }


    public ClicksCount1(Button oButton, Label oLabel)
    {
        _oButton = oButton;
        _oLabel = oLabel;

        _oLabel.Text = _clickCount.ToString();

        _oButton.Click += _oButton_Click;


    }

    void _oButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _clickCount++;
    }
}
```

2.

```
    public class ClicksCount2 : Panel
{
    Button _oButton = new Button() {Location = new Point(10,10)};
    Label _oLabel = new Label() {Location = new Point(100,10)};

    int _clickCount = 0;
    public int ClickCount {
        get {
            return _clickCount;
        }
        set {
            _clickCount = value;
            _oLabel.Text = _clickCount.ToString();
        }
    }

    public ClicksCount2()
    {
        _oLabel.Text = _clickCount.ToString();

        _oButton.Click += _oButton_Click;

        this.Controls.Add(_oButton);
        this.Controls.Add(_oLabel);
    }

    void _oButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ClickCount++;
    }
}
```

3.

```
public class ClicksCount3 : Button
{
    Label _oLabel = new Label();

    int _clickCount = 0;
    public int ClickCount {
        get {
            return _clickCount;
        }
        set {
            _clickCount = value;
            _oLabel.Text = _clickCount.ToString();
        }
    }

    public ClicksCount3()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();

        _oLabel.Location = new Point(this.Location.X+100,this.Location.Y);
        _oLabel.Text = _clickCount.ToString();
        this.Parent.Controls.Add(_oLabel);
    }

    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMove(e);

        _oLabel.Location = new Point(this.Location.X+100,this.Location.Y);
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);

        ClickCount++;
    }

    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);

        this.Parent.Controls.Remove(_oLabel);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        _oLabel.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you need to investigate the concept of [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear to me what you try to achieve. But i think you need to use [UserControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). UserControls gives you the chance to create own custom controls. It just gives you a container where you can place any components and controls. For example a Button and a Label. In general i would not recommend you to send controls to your classes. In your example you should create a UserControl and send your class to it. So your class don't know any gui componentes and stays independent. Further you could try to use [MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp).

Comment: Like to hear that. If you have further questions don't hesitate to come in touch with me.